# Bootstrap navigation bar is not working properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navigationbar

I'm learning `Bootstrap 3` to develop my personal website. 
I have an issue with the navigation bar, that seems to not be working properly.

Here is a screenshot of the current situation

[image]

istead, it should be something like this ...

[image]

I've tried to change `margin-top` values but it's not working either.
And here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="height:1500px">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#page1">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#page2">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#page3">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container" style="margin-top:50px" id="page1">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. 
</div>

<div class="container" style="margin-top:50px" id="page2">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. 
</div>

<div class="container" style="margin-top:50px" id="page3">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. 
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

What do you suggest, please. Thank you

Comment: your code ? you need to add it

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam hahahha sorry for that. I added the code.

Comment: thats ok, :) see below answer by nicholas

Answer (score -1):

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar

Body padding required

The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add padding to the top of the `<body>`. Try out your own values or use our snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is 50px high.

`body { padding-top: 70px; }`

Make sure to include this after the core Bootstrap CSS.